# Error: "use of class template requires template class argument" using linked lists

Tags: c++, templates

Below is the piece of code that is generating the error "Use of class template requires template class argument", in the program I am using linked lists. I have been searching for a solution to the problem, but no luck whatsoever. I know it is related to the use of templates but haven't found a clear solution to the problem. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
    template <class dato>
ListaEnlazada& ListaEnlazada<dato>::operator= (const ListaEnlazada& otra) {
    if (this != &otra)
    {
        vaciar();
        agregar(otra);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify a template argument in the return type. The compiler does not implicitly attach a template argument to uses of the class name until it is in the scope of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax needs to declare explicitely the template argument in every place:

```
template <class dato>
ListaEnlazada<dato>& ListaEnlazada<dato>::operator= (const ListaEnlazada<dato>& otra) {
    if (this != &otra)
    {
        vaciar();
        agregar(otra);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
template <class dato>
ListaEnlazada<dato>& ListaEnlazada<dato>::operator= … 
             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: No luck yet, 12 new errors popped out. My code works perfectly without templates but I have to use templates, its a requirement. Thanks for the suggestion!